# What's the easiest way to add files to the Android system partition?

Tags: root-access, system

I need to add a root certificate to Android systems. I hope to achieve this by copying the appropriate file the following path: /system/etc/security/cacerts, or using a flashable zip.

Due to the fact that applications from Android version 7 and upwards no longer trust user-added CAs by default, I will need to do this to many tens of devices from multiple vendors.

**Possible methods:**

1. Rooting the devices
2. Via a custom recovery

**Drawbacks:**

Rooting:

- I will need to separately find a method of rooting each device. There
  is no generic rooting method that will work for all devices.

Custom recovery:

- I will need to obtain multiple customized TWRP (or other) recovery images, one for each device model.
- Not all devices have custom recovery images available.

Is there an easier and more generic method to achieve my goal?

Comment: it is OEMs ambition to avoid ROM manipulation, android becomes more and more secure with each version. for example Huawei stopped unlocking completely, and they recently introduced Extendable Read-Only File System "EROFS" which makes it "impossible" to add files (without flashing whole partition, at least). conclusion, Magisk and TWRP already are the most easiest and generic methods we can expect in future. Leave the rooting part at users responsibility, just create a generic Flashable zip or a Magisk Xposed module

Comment: Installing Magisk requires root or costam recovery?
This model requires root?
https://github.com/NVISO-BE/MagiskTrustUserCerts

Comment: Magisk IS root..